# XeLaTeX changing linespacing after macro

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

I have document for theses, and I noticed that line spacing changed after macro, creating part headline. I cant figure out what could cause this. If anyone has some idea let me know.

this is the macro:

```
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{part}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thepart~~\uppercase{#1}}%
  \clearpage
  \normalfont
  \vspace*{9cm}
 \begin{center}\huge \bfseries\thepart. \uppercase{#1}\end{center}%
 \markboth{}{}\par
 \nobreak
 \clearpage  
}
```

here is editable source document: https://www.writelatex.com/1099369kwfvst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\normalfont` in the wrong place (and also other flaws):

```
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{part}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thepart~~\uppercase{#1}}%
  \vspace*{9cm}
  \begin{center}
    \normalfont\huge\bfseries
    \thepart. \uppercase{#1}
  \end{center}
  \markboth{}{}
  \cleardoublepage
}
```

The `\normalfont` was causing the issue. You probably want also

```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thepart~~\texorpdfstring{\uppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
```

in order to avoid warnings from `hyperref`. The same should be in

```
\newcommand{\upc}[1]{% zjednodušení pro velká písmena
  \texorpdfstring{\uppercase{#1}}{#1}}
```

and possibly in other places where `\uppercase` is used.

You need also

```
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
```

as `fancyhdr` warns you to.

Finally, the `BCOR=10mm` is unknown to the `article` class. The package `hyperref` should be loaded last. Don't load `xltxtra`, but rather `fontspec`.

Comment: Thank's a lot that is absolutely brilliant answer. Thanks a lot. I was wrestling with these warnings for some time.